# Compilation fail with "std::filesystem" on raspberry

Tags: c++, std-filesystem

I have "Raspberry Pi 3 Model B" with "Raspbian Buster with desktop" installed on SD-card.

I installed all the necessary to compile with g++:

```
gcc (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) 8.3.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I created a small test file (test.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
int main()
{
    for(fs::path p : {"/var/tmp/example.txt", "/", "/var/tmp/."})
        std::cout << "The parent path of " << p
                  << " is " << p.parent_path() << '\n';
}
```

and compiled with the command:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors test.cpp -o test
```

but compilation fail with error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cckH4cTy.o: in function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::parent_path() const'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cckH4cTy.o: in function `std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::path<char const*, std::filesystem::__cxx11::path>(char const* const&, std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::format)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZNSt10filesystem7__cxx114pathC2IPKcS1_EERKT_NS1_6formatE[_ZNSt10filesystem7__cxx114pathC5IPKcS1_EERKT_NS1_6formatE]+0x70): undefined reference to `std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_M_split_cmpts()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How to solve ?

Comment: add `-lstdc++fs` to compilation command or upgrade to gcc 9.

Comment: I have add "-lstdc++fs" to compilation command : "g++ -std=c++17 -lstdc++fs -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors test.cpp -o test" but error remain

Comment: You put it in the wrong place. You need your `-l` _after_ the TU that depends on it (`test.cpp`). https://stackoverflow.com/q/45135/4386278

Comment: With "g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors test.cpp -lstdc++fs -o test" compilation successfully